# Paying for multiple items (at once) via paypal

Tags: html, paypal, payment-gateway

I have a list of products that I'd like to add a "pay now" button to so that I can allow my customers to pay via Paypal.

I've gone through the documentation and can't find how to do this.
I can add multiple items, but this is not going to be handy as I already have the list of items to process.
I also need the checkout process to itemize the order, so a "buy now" with 1 price is no good either.

Any help appreciated guys, I tried (with no luck):

```
<form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="email@domain.com">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="GB">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="test 1">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name2" value="test 2">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number2" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name3" value="test 3">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number3" value="3">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="99.00">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="products">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-ShopCartBF:btn_cart_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_GB/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online.">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

See this sample and make the changes to yours accordingly. Basically add underscore to item name before number and give unique name to amount also with underscore and number.

You have to give amount to each item based on your carts totals.

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="youremail@mail.com">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">

<input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="beach ball">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="15">

<input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="towel">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_2" value="20">

<input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-but01.gif" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
</form>
```

**Specify Quantity(optional)**

```
<input type="hidden" name="quantity_1" value="1">
```

for more reference about cart: [Paypal Cart](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/cart-upload/#implement-the-cart-upload-command)

Comment: How do you specify varying quantities for each item?

Comment: @JosephPersie I've updated the answer. Also check out this link for a more detail answer https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/About-Selling/how-do-i-add-a-quot-quantity-quot-option-to-my-button-ie-5-x/td-p/480148

Answer (score 0):

it will not work in

```
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
```

please update me if you know multiple item payment option in recurrent payment method or in any ways i can add tax in this method.

Comment: It should be `_cart` instead of `_xclick-subscriptions`

Answer (score -1):

PayPal Add to Cart button helps you to accept payment for multiple items. The button HTML will like the following.

```
<form target="_self" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="paypal@email.com">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="PHP Book">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="PB123">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="25">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type='hidden' name='cancel_return' value='http://www.example.com/cancel.php'>
<input type='hidden' name='return' value='http://www.example.com/success.php'>
<input type="image" name="submit"
src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/i/btn/png/btn_addtocart_120x26.png"
alt="Add to Cart">
<img alt="" width="1" height="1" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif">
</form>
```