# Paypal multiple items in URL

Tags: redirect, paypal

I have a `Redirect` to take the buyer to the Paypal cart.  The URL it forwards them to is (formatted for readability):

```
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick
&business=email@domain.com
&pal=BGUR9WCWZAL7G
&button_subtype=services
&no_note=1
&no_shipping=1
&rm=1
&return=http://127.0.0.1/store/thank-you
&cancel_return=http://127.0.0.1/store/payment-cancelled
&shipping=0.00
&custom=LoggedInUser|45
&currency_code=EUR
&item_name_1=Store 9 Item
&amount_1=12.00
&item_name_2=Something else
&amount_2=24.00
```

I can't use Post data for design reasons.

If I have it as a single item by passing `&amount=1&item_name=5 Store Items` it works fine, but I need to break it down into individual items if possible.

Is this do-able?  I see this question:
[Paying for multiple items (at once) via paypal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308898/paying-for-multiple-items-at-once-via-paypal)

But it's for posting, not a url

Comment: What do you mean this is a redirect? Like a buy now type button?

Comment: @David, yes it's a URL to redirect to which asks the user to buy something, much like a buy now button

Comment: I really don't think is possible at all, it doesn't look like it is a documented method at all. The fact that it takes `item_name` instead of `item_name_1` looks like an indication that it doesn't accept multiple items. Why can't you use POST data?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try the cart upload method. See [this page](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_cart_upload) for more information.

It will basically turn out something like this:

```
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_cart
&business=email@domain.com
&pal=BGUR9WCWZAL7G
&button_subtype=services
&upload=1
&no_note=1
&rm=1
&return=http://127.0.0.1/store/thank-you
&cancel_return=http://127.0.0.1/store/payment-cancelled
&currency_code=EUR
&item_name_1=Store 9 Item
&amount_1=12.00
&quantity_1=1
&shipping_1=0.00
&item_name_2=Something else
&amount_2=24.00
&quantity_2=1
&shipping_2=0.00
```