# Variable 3rd party paypal Shopping cart

Tags: php, paypal

Simply put a flexible check out paypal button using your own shopping cart.

one that sends each product plus quantity to the paypal payment page.
I've seen codes for multiple products, but those are not flexible. for example Payment for 2 unique items. but what about if the user buys X amount of different products? when only allows a fixed amount.

Referring to [This page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308898/paying-for-multiple-items-at-once-via-paypal)

Is this possible to do in PHP? If so I was thinking of something easy like an array listing each product with in the button form.

Answer (score 1):

This would be possible.  However, you would want to have some logic on your side that would check to see that amount that they are wanting to order and check it against your database to see the quantity that you have on hand.  If they try to order more than you have on hand, you would give them a pop up telling that you only have x number on hand and that they can not order more than x amount.  Then you would just populate the details and quantity that they ordered, and pass it over using the cart upload method similar to the example you provided.

Comment: aye, that would be a good thing to do. thanks for the suggestion