# How to allow the option of increasing the tickets purchased

Tags: html, paypal

Ok, the code below works. But the thing is that it doesn't allow the user to alter the amount purchased.

I'm trying to figure out how to have the user, once they've purchased a ticket and get to paypal page, to be able to alter the amount of tickets they would like to have.

As it is, once you land on the paypal page, it shows what you purchased, and that's it, pretty much.

Any advice?

EDIT

If anyone needs an example of what I'm talking about, here's one: [Paying for multiple items (at once) via paypal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308898/paying-for-multiple-items-at-once-via-paypal)

Look at the image at bottom. Do you see the quantity column? That's what I meant. But when I tried what they did in that one, it doesn't work. I think it's because in that one, it uses _cart, wheres mine is _donation?

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">

<!-- Specify a Donate button. -->
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_donations">

<!-- Specify details about the contribution -->
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Name Of Business">

<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="Tickets"> 
<select name="amount">
    <optgroup label="Sponsorship">
         <option value="15000" name="platinum">$15,000 - Platinum Sponsorship</option>
         <option value="10000">$10,000 - Gold Sponsorship</option>
         <option value="5000">$5000 - Silver Sponsorship</option>
         <option value="2500">$2,500 - Bronze Sponsorship</option>
   </optgroup>
   <optgroup label="Individual Seating">
         <option value="500">$500 per seat</option>
   </optgroup>
         <optgroup label="Program Book Tribute Journal Ad">
         <option value="600">$600 - Half Page</option>
         <option value="1000">$1000 - Full Page</option>
   </optgroup>

</select>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">


<br /><br />
<!-- Display the payment button. -->
<input type="image" name="submit" border="0"
 src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donate_LG.gif"
 alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">
 <img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1"
 src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" >
 </form>
```

**EDIT TWO**

Ok, kinda confused about how to get the item increments to show up.

Advice would be appreciated.

These are the changes I've added to the post above:

```
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
```

Then to have the increment ability added ... I'm really confused by these lines and how to make it work for mine.

```
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Item Name 1">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="1.00">
```

So, for the first item in my drop-down box (ie, the platinum ticket), I've modified it slightly, adding the name value:

```
<option value="15000" name="platinum">$15,000 - Platinum Sponsorship</option>
```

And then,

```
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="platinum">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="15000.00">
```

But as far as I can tell, that doesn't allow the user to change the quantity to what they want.

**End of EDIT TWO**

**EDIT THREE** Based on Jared's code beneath but posting a full version of it.

```
  <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">

   <!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->
   <input type="hidden" name="business" value="BLAHBLAH">

   <!-- Specify a Donate button. -->
   <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
   <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">

   <!-- Specify details about the contribution -->
   <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Corporation">

   <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="Ticket Purchase"> 
   <select name="amount">
      <optgroup label="Sponsorship">
         <option value="Platinum Sponsorship">$15,000 - Platinum Sponsorship</option>
         <option value="Gold Sponsorship">$10,000 - Gold Sponsorship</option>
      </optgroup>
  </select>
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
  <input type="hidden" name="option_select0" value="Platinum Sponsorship">
  <input type="hidden" name="option_amount0" value="15000.00">
  <input type="hidden" name="option_select1" value="Gold Sponsorship">
  <input type="hidden" name="option_amount1" value="10000.00">
  <input type="hidden" name="option_index" value="0">
  <br /><br />
  <!-- Display the payment button. -->
  <input type="image" name="submit" border="0"
  src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donate_LG.gif"
  alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">
  <img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1"
 src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" >
 </form>
```

All I get from this form is `Your shopping cart is empty.`

**END OF EDIT THREE**

**EDIT FOUR**

```
1. <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Donation">
2. <input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="products">
3. <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
4. <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2">
5. <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
6. <input type="hidden" name="weight_unit" value="lbs">
7. <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
8. <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-ShopCartBF:btn_cart_LG.gif:NonHosted">
```

Do we need 2, 3, 4, & 6?

I get one, it's a way to label it, right?

2, what is button_subtype?

3, that's to say that there is no more additional info included, right?

4, is that needed? it's just purchase of a ticket online.

5, obviously needed.

6, is weight_unit really needed? as mentioned previously, it's just an online ticket.

7, is? I'm guessing a way for the incrementation to happen?

8, is to denote that the button is not hosted from paypal, right?

You don't have to answer any of those questions, and your answer has been accepted. Just wondering, is all.

Thank you again, Jared.

**END OF EDIT FOUR**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" >
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="Your Email Here">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Donation">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="products">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="weight_unit" value="lbs">
<input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-ShopCartBF:btn_cart_LG.gif:NonHosted">
<table>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Sponsorship"></td></tr><tr><td><select name="os0">
<optgroup label="Sponsorship">
    <option value="Platinum Sponsorship">Platinum Sponsorship $15,00.00 USD</option>
    <option value="Gold Sponsorship">Gold Sponsorship $10,000.00 USD</option>
</optgroup>
</select> </td></tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="option_select0" value="Platinum Sponsorship">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount0" value="15000.00">
<input type="hidden" name="option_select1" value="Gold Sponsorship">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount1" value="10000.00">
<input type="hidden" name="option_index" value="0">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donate_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

This is how your button should look, this is from paypal.

Comment: And you wont be able to do the 15,000 option btw, Paypal only allows 10,000 max per transaction.

Comment: oh my gosh! this worked!!!!!! yay!!!!! and thank you for telling me that the max is 10,000. wasn't aware of that. will pass that info onwards. just a couple of questions though, which i'm posting in my post, but otherwise, this answer is totally accepted! thank you again!!!!

Comment: have included my questions in edit 4. It's totally up to you if you want to answer it or not.

Answer (score 0):

The donation button does not allow you to use a quanity because its intended for a donation, not a purchase. You can, however have the function of the add to cart button but appear as a donation button. Simply:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">

<!-- Specify a Add to Cart button. -->
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">

<!-- Specify details about the contribution -->
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Name Of Business">

<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="Tickets"> 
<select name="amount">
    <optgroup label="Sponsorship">
         <option value="15000" name="platinum">$15,000 - Platinum Sponsorship</option>
         <option value="10000">$10,000 - Gold Sponsorship</option>
         <option value="5000">$5000 - Silver Sponsorship</option>
         <option value="2500">$2,500 - Bronze Sponsorship</option>
   </optgroup>
   <optgroup label="Individual Seating">
         <option value="500">$500 per seat</option>
   </optgroup>
         <optgroup label="Program Book Tribute Journal Ad">
         <option value="600">$600 - Half Page</option>
         <option value="1000">$1000 - Full Page</option>
   </optgroup>

</select>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">


<br /><br />
<!-- Display the Donation payment button. -->
<input type="image" name="submit" border="0"
 src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donate_LG.gif"
 alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">
 <img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1"
 src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" >
 </form>
```

Comment: and it'll still be considered a donation for the business, right?

Comment: wait, I'm confused. Your code post, is it supposed to work as is? Ie, I don't need to add any other changes besides _cart?

Comment: Right, you can change the value to which ever paypal button functionality you want. ie: _cart, _donations, _xclick(buy it now).

Comment: The part

`<input type="image" name="submit" border="0"
 src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donate_LG.gif"`

is the piece that gives it the appearance of the button.

Comment: I get that. What I meant is that as far as I can see ... the only change you've put in the code above is _cart. What I meant was that ... would that add the ability for the user to increment the purchase as needed? (edit is coming up in post by the way. two minutes or so)

Comment: well have you tested this? or possibly testing it with _xclick?

Comment: just posted my edit above. I've tested this with _cart.

Comment: The user will be able to change the increments within PayPal, or simply click the donations button 5 times with _cart

Comment: _donations allows one "donation" at a time, its not intended to have the functionality of adding Multiple donations.

Comment: yeah, that's not really realistic asking the user to click on the donation button 5 times. And did you see my 2nd edit? It still doesn't allow the user to edit the amount of quantity as wanted. Any advice on item_name_1 code? Am I doing that wrongly?

Comment: `<input type="hidden" name="option_select0" value="platinum">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount0" value="15000.00">`

Comment: and also, the user can either click the button 5 times for 5 tickets OR edit the quantity in the checkout screen of paypal

Comment: I tried your option_select code, and I get this: `Your shopping cart is empty.`

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="hidden" name="Ticket"><select name="os0">
<optgroup label="Sponsorship">
    <option value="Platinum Sponsorship">$15,000 - Platinum Sponsorship</option>
    <option value="Gold Sponsorship">$10,000 - Gold Sponsorship</option>
</optgroup>
</select> 
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="option_select0" value="Platinum Sponsorship">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount0" value="15000.00">
<input type="hidden" name="option_select1" value="Gold Sponsorship">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount1" value="10000.00">
<input type="hidden" name="option_index" value="0">
```

Comment: Please look at my edit 3 of my post above. Copied your code. Got this error `Your shopping cart is empty.`