# Paypal Pay now button : Multiple fees description for single item

Tags: paypal, paypal-buttons

I am using Paypal's "Pay now" button and I would like to show several fee details for an item in the paypal checkout form. I would like to have something like this :
[image]

The user would have clicked only once for the item "111 Wilshire blvd" and the checkout should show two additional fee's with custom descriptions "Application fee", "xxx cost"

Is it possible to do that with "pay now" button? If not, which paypal product should I use to be able to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always add multiple items in a single form request.

See this SO question:

[Paying for multiple items (at once) via paypal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308898/paying-for-multiple-items-at-once-via-paypal)