# How to create a paypal with more items?

Tags: php

i'm creating a php page with ipn of paypal. But I can't send from my form more items to paypal. Can you help me please?
Thx

---

It doesn't work. This is my code:

```
<form name="_xclick" action="paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"; method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="MAIL">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Name">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="ISCR" />
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="15.00">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution: 
Just duplicate the

```
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Item">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="1.00">
```

To

```
<input type="hidden" name="item_name1" value="Item 1">
<input type="hidden" name="amount1" value="1.00">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name2" value="Item 2">
<input type="hidden" name="amount2" value="1.00">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name3" value="Item 3">
<input type="hidden" name="amount3" value="1.00">
```

Reference:
[submitting multiple items to paypal cart at once with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761803/submitting-multiple-items-to-paypal-cart-at-once-with-php)